# Google Line Charts v-axes overlaps when more than 2 are added

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, linechart

Adding more than 2 v-axes to Google line chart makes the ones on the right overlap.
Use Sample code function for repro in https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart

Sample code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 2');
  data.addRow(["A", 1, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["B", 2, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["C", 4, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["D", 8, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["E", 7, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["F", 7, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["G", 8, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["H", 4, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["I", 2, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["J", 3.5, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["K", 3, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["L", 3.5, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["M", 1, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["N", 1, 0.5, 1]);


  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data, {curveType: "function",width: 500, height: 400,
    vAxes: {0: {logScale: false},
            1: {logScale: false, maxValue: 10},
            2:{logScale:false}},
    series:{
       0:{targetAxisIndex:0},
       1:{targetAxisIndex:1},
       2:{targetAxisIndex:2}}}
          );
}
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: One possibility is to use `textPosition: 'out'` for one axis and `textPosition: 'in'` for the other. Not the best one but at least numbers are not overlapping.

Comment: The chart's don't support more than two `vAxes` very well, you're only real option is to do what @Anto Jurković mentioned.  You can file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) for improved support of more than 2 `vAxes`.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment: One possibility is to use `textPosition: 'out'` for one axis and `textPosition: 'in'` for the other. In that case you get numbers which are not overlapping.

There is one `risky` option: to change DOM elements 'manually'. Axis labels have following tag and properties in DOM (x and y values are different):

```
<text text-anchor="start" x="452" y="327.7" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">0,40</text>
```

Axis labels bellow x-axis have property text-anchor 'middle', labels left of chart have value 'end', those on the right side and legend marks have value 'start'. Those which are overlapping have the same x value, y is different. So, half of them have to be moved right (x value changed):

```
...
var labels = document.querySelectorAll('text[text-anchor=start]');

// find limits of same x
var xMin = -1, xMax = -1;
for (var i = 1; i < labels.length; i++) {
    if (labels[i - 1].attributes[1].value == labels[i].attributes[1].value) {
        if (xMin == -1 ) xMin = i - 1;
        xMax = i;
    }
}

if (xMax != -1) {
    // change just half of them
    for (var i = xMin + (xMax - xMin + 1)/2; i <= xMax; i++) {
        var value = parseInt(labels[i].attributes[1].value);
        labels[i].attributes[1].value = value + 35;
    }
}
...
```

This is just for exercise, I wouldn't use it because it will fail the first time google decide to change text-anchor to something else or something change in the label sequence or someone decide to put 2 axes to the left side...

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/noda/1/edit)